# C# BackgroundWorker

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, backgroundworker

I have a button that on click event I get some information from the network.

When I get information I parse it and add items to ListBox. All is fine, but when I do a fast double-click  on button, it seems that two background workers are running and after finishing all work, items in the list are dublicated.

I want to do so that if you click button and the proccess of getting information is in work, this thread is stopping and only after first work is completed the second one is beginning. 
Yes, I know about AutoResetEvent, but when I used it it helped me only one time and never more. I can't implement this situation and hope that you will help me!

Now I even try to make easier but no success :( : I added a flag field(RefreshDialogs)(default false), when the user clicks on button, if flag is true(it means that work is doing), nothing is doing, but when flag field is set to false, all is fine and we start a new proccess. 
When Backgroundwork completes, I change field flag to false(it means that user can run a new proccess).

```
    private void Message_Refresh_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!RefreshDialogs)
        {
            RefreshDialogs = true;
            if (threadBackgroundDialogs.WorkerSupportsCancellation)
            {
                threadBackgroundDialogs.CancelAsync();
            }
            if (!threadBackgroundDialogs.IsBusy)
            {
                downloadedDialogs = 0;
                threadBackgroundDialogs = new BackgroundWorker();
                threadBackgroundDialogs.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
                threadBackgroundDialogs.DoWork += LoadDialogs;
                threadBackgroundDialogs.RunWorkerCompleted += ProcessCompleted;
                threadBackgroundDialogs.RunWorkerAsync();
            }
        }
    }
    void ProcessCompleted(object sender,  RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        RefreshDialogs = false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not an Windows Phone expert, but as I see it has support for TPL, so following code would read nicely:

```
private object syncRoot =new object();
private Task latestTask;

public void EnqueueAction(System.Action action)
{
    lock (syncRoot)
    {
        if (latestTask == null)
            latestTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(action);
        else
            latestTask = latestTask.ContinueWith(tsk => action());
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure? There is no System.Threading.Tasks in Windows Phone OS SDK 7.1

Comment: @igla: haven't investigated, just saw this package: http://nuget.org/packages/System.Threading.Tasks

Answer (score 2):

So you want to keep the second process running while the first works, but they shouldn't disturb each other? And after the first one finishes the second one continues?

Crude way: While loop:

```
        if (!RefreshDialogs)
    {
        RefreshDialogs = true;
```

this becomes:

```
    while(RefreshDialogs)
    {
    }
        RefreshDialogs = true;
```

After you set it false the second process wwill jump out of the while. (Note this is extremly inefficent since both processes will be running all the time, i'm pretty sure the second one will block the first one, but with multitasking now it shouldn't, if it block use a Dispatcher.Thread)

Elegant way: Use A Semaphore

http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.threading.semaphore%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

If you find it impossible to have both processes running at the same time, or want another way:
Add an Array/List/int and when the second process notices there is the first process running, like with your bool, increase your Added variable, and at the end of the process, restart the new process and decrese the variable:

```
    int number;

    if (!RefreshDialogs)
    {
        RefreshDialogs = true;
        your code;
        if(number > 0)
        {
          number--;
          restart process
        }
    }
    else
    {
    number++;
    }
```

I have to admit, i like my last proposal the most, since its highly efficent.

Comment: If the first process is running and user clicked on button again, the first process should stop and the second one must begin

Comment: @igla .. well.. should the first process afterwards continue?

Answer (score 1):

Make your thread blocking. That is easy;

```
lock(someSharedGlobalObject)
{
  Do Work, Exit early if cancelled
}
```

This way other threads will wait until the first thread releases the lock. They will never execute simultaneously and silently wait until they can continue.

As for other options; why not disable the button when clicked and re-enable it when the backgroundworker completes. Only problem is this does not allow for cancelling the current thread. The user has to wait for it to finish. It does make any concurrency go away very easily.

Comment: Because it's important not to confuse user and give him a full application control

Comment: Yes, your solution seems very good, I will say about results when I will learn 'lock' and add it to applicatiom

Comment: If the first process is running and user clicked on button again, the first process should stop and the second one must begin. But in your solution threads will run in queue...

Comment: you still need to set a boolean or other signal so that the running thread (which has the lock) will stop. As soon as it stops the next thread will acquire the lock and go to work.

Answer (score 1):

How about this approach?

Create a request queue or counter which will be incremented on every button click. Every time that count is > 0. Start the background worker. When the information comes, decrement the count and check for 0. If its still > 0 restart the worker. In that your request handler becomes sequential.

In this approach you may face the problem of continuous reference of the count by two threads, for that you may use a lock unlock condition.

I hav followed this approach for my app and it works well, hope it does the same for you.

Answer (score 0):

Use can use semaphores

```
  class TheClass
 {
    static SemaphoreSlim _sem = new SemaphoreSlim (3);

    static void Main()   
    {     
       for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) 
       new Thread (Enter).Start (i);   
    } 

    static void Enter (object name)   
    {     
      Console.WriteLine (name + " wants to enter");    
      _sem.Wait();     
      Console.WriteLine (name + " has entered!");               
      Thread.Sleep (1000 * (int) name );              
      Console.WriteLine (name + " is leaving");       
      _sem.Release();   } 
     }
 }
```

Comment: I'am writing for Windows Phone and there are not semaphores(

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution and thanks to @Giedrius. Flag RefreshingDialogs is set to true only when proccess is at the end, when I added items to Listbox. The reason why I'am using this flag is that state of process changes to complete when the asynchronous operation of getting content from network(HttpWebRequest, method BeginGetRequestStream) begins, but after network operaion is complete I need to make UI operations and not only them(parse content and add it to Listbox)My solution is:

```
    private object syncRoot = new object();
    private Task latestTask;

    public void EnqueueAction(System.Action action)
    {
        lock (syncRoot)
        {
            if (latestTask == null)
            {
                downloadedDialogs = 0;
                latestTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(action);
            }
            else if(latestTask.IsCompleted && !RefreshingDialogs)
            {
                RefreshingDialogs = true;
                downloadedDialogs = 0;
                latestTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(action);
            }
        }
    }

    private void Message_Refresh_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Action ac = new Action(LoadDialogs2);
        EnqueueAction(ac);
    }
```